# How to order instances of two different collections by a property from parent type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core I'm working with this model of entities:

```
public abstract Foo
{
public string FooID { get; set; }
public DateTime TimeOfCreation { get; set; }
}

public FirstFoo : Foo
{ /* some properties */ }

public SecondFoo : Foo
{ /* some properties */ }
```

I use the table-per-concrete type pattern, i.e. EF will create two different tables for FirstFoo and SecondFoo.

Now my target is order all concrete instances of Foo (both from two tables) by shared property `TimeOfCreation`.
Can I do it? I want to get one  `Foo`-type collection where can be either `FirstFoo` and `SecondFoo` samples.

Comment: You can create a list of Foo and add results from FirstFoo and SecondFoo to order by TimeOfCreation

Comment: @H. Herzl I want to order these entities by time and take 10 (for e.g.) most recent from them. So I think that taking 10 instances from both  tables with following comparison is extremely not elegant approach.

Comment: Something like this? var list = new List<Foo>();

// Code for add FirstFoo
list.AddRange(dbContext.FirstFoo.ToList());

// Code for add SecondFoo
list.AddRange(dbContext.SecondFoo.ToList());

var result = list.OrderByDescending(item => item.TimeOfCreation).Take(10);